# html table scroll color

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I am new to HTML/CSS world. I need to change scroll bar color of the table. 
I understand how to make scrollbar appear, but I don't know how to change scrollbar color. I need for this to work in IE11. ( I can't use JavaScript or anything else...just plain html/css)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: check it here : http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3470421

Comment: Your question is still a duplicate of the one referenced above. The solutions mentioned there are **not** using JavaScript. They are CSS.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hmartiro/Xck2A/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/tRbCs/

Answer (score 0):

try these CSS properties:

```
scrollbar-face-color
scrollbar-shadow-color
scrollbar-highlight-color
scrollbar-3dlight-color
scrollbar-darkshadow-color
scrollbar-track-color
scrollbar-arrow-color
```